# not importing class from name-sources.jar

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I have created a maven war project, and want to call it from another module (war). When I searched found that name-sources.jar file is used as dependency to another module. I am adding dependency of name-sources but import is not working.

```
name-SNAPSHOT.war
name-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
```

are the files generated on building of maven project.
Below is the dependency added into another module.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>uniqueid</groupId>
<artifactId>name</artifactId>
<version>8.9-SNAPSHOT</version>         
<classifier>sources</classifier>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>{Path}/name-8.9-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's really hard understanding the problem you're having...

Comment: First never use system scopes dependencies. Furthermore use simple dependencies...Why would you like to use `sources` in a war project?

Comment: Why would you use .war as a dependency to your another war project? Adding a dependency in a Maven project is pretty straightforward.

Comment: if i am not adding sources it's trying to pull from nexus where this new jar doesn't exist. secondly, I have created a web module which has to be deployed as war and also to be called from another existing web module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created *-classes.jar file. Use below code under pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>                    
    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And added this new jar as dependency wherever want to use.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.honeywell.dras.sensibo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sensibo-client</artifactId>
        <version>{*}</version>          
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

So advantage with this is we can generate both war and jar files and make use of both based on need.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this: you have 2 web projects **A** and **B**, both with maven packaging = war. In **A**, there are classes you want to use in **B**.

Forget about adding a `*-sources.jar` as dependency.

So, do this:

1. generate a new maven project **C** as a library with project packaging "jar"
2. Move the classes you want to share from **A** to **C**
3. Install this artifact **C** in your local maven repository (`mvn install`)
4. Then, add a dependency to **C** in the `pom.xml`s of **A** and **B**:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>your.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>yourLibrary</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</compile> <!-- this is default, so this line is optional-->
</dependency>
```